# How to return an array with the first 2 elements in an object and iterate until the end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, loops, object

I just want to return an array containing the first and second objects of the element.

The next 2 elements will be repeated after traversing the keys

Given the following object:

```
const object = {
  a: [
    { name: "John", age: 32 },
    { name: "David", age: 23 },
    { name: "Justin", age: 28 },
    { name: "Arnauld", age: 35 }
  ],
  b: [
    { name: "Ivan", age: 18 },
    { name: "Nekko", age: 13 },
    { name: "Lena", age: 25 }
  ],
  c: [
    { name: "Ann", age: 19 },
    { name: "Nick", age: 14 }
  ]
};
```

the result I want is

```
[
  { name: "John", age: 32 },
  { name: "David", age: 23 },
  { name: "Ivan", age: 18 },
  { name: "Nekko", age: 13 },
  { name: "Ann", age: 19 },
  { name: "Nick", age: 14 },
  { name: "Justin", age: 28 },
  { name: "Arnauld", age: 35 },
  { name: "Lena", age: 25 }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried? We're here to solve problems with existing code, not write new code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object.values() and then you can use array.reduce() to get desire values.

```
const object = {
   a: [
     { name: "John", age: 32 },
     { name: "David", age: 23 },
     { name: "Justin", age: 28 },
     { name: "Arnauld", age: 35 }
   ],
   b: [
     { name: "Ivan", age: 18 },
     { name: "Nekko", age: 13 },
     { name: "Lena", age: 25 }
   ],
   c: [
     { name: "Ann", age: 19 },
     { name: "Nick", age: 14 }
   ]
};

let newArray = Object.values(object).reduce((prev, current) => ([...prev, ...current.slice(0,2)]),[]);
console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: The code above does not get the required results... Your missing the second iteration.

Justin, Arnauld and Lena also need to be added to the array. Check out my solution and see what it logs in console.log

Answer (score 1):

```js
const object = {
  a: [
    { name: "John", age: 32 },
    { name: "David", age: 23 },
    { name: "Justin", age: 28 },
    { name: "Arnauld", age: 35 }
  ],
  b: [
    { name: "Ivan", age: 18 },
    { name: "Nekko", age: 13 },
    { name: "Lena", age: 25 }
  ],
  c: [
    { name: "Ann", age: 19 },
    { name: "Nick", age: 14 }
  ]
};

const result = Object.values(object).reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const arr = cur.map((item, index) => {
    return { ...item, index: Math.floor(index / 2) };
  });
    
  return [...acc, ...arr];
}, []).sort((a,b) => a.index - b.index);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

this gives exact the order as you requested it.

**EDIT**

Explanation:

The solution iterates over `Object.values()` array and uses `.reduce()` in order to first assign an `index` to each element (in the arrays corresponding to keys `a`, `b`, `c`.

Then, it uses `.sort()` to obtain the desired order in the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

```
const names = [];
while (true) {
    let test = false;
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
        if (value.length > 0) {
            const arrays = value.splice(0, 2)
            names.push(...arrays)
            test = true
        }
    }
    if (test === false) break;
}
console.log(names);
```

i think something like this will do, but be careful using splice because it'll delete the values from the array

Answer (score 0):

Or try This **shorter** approach:

```
let result = [];
Object.entries(object).map((item) => {
  result.push(item[1][0], item[1][1]);
});

 // This will return your desired result
console.log(result)
```

Calling `Object.entries()` generate an array with all its enumerable properties.

Answer (score 0):

Presented below is one possible way to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const myTransform = obj => (
  Object.values(obj)
  .reduce(
    (acc, itm) => (
      acc.concat(
        itm.map(
          (elt, idx) => ({
            ...elt,
            index: Math.floor(idx / 2)
          })
        )
      )
    ),
    []
  )
  .sort(
    (
      {index : aIdx},
      {index: bIdx}
    ) => aIdx - bIdx
  )
  .map(
    (
      {index, ...rest}
    ) => ({...rest})
  )
);

/*
// method to transform object into desired array
const myTransform = obj => (
  // extract the values of the object, as an array
  Object.values(obj)
  // iterate over the values using ".reduce()"
  .reduce(
    // "acc" is the accumulator, "itm" is iterator/item
    (acc, itm) => (
      // concat result of inner-expression to "acc" 
      acc.concat(
        // iterate over "itm" array
        itm.map(
          // for each object, add "index" as a prop
          (elt, index) => ({
            ...elt,
            // value of index is ".floor()" of index/position / 2
            // this ensures all elts in 0, 1 are with index 0
            // and elts in 2, 3 are with index 1, so on...
            index: Math.floor(idx / 2)
          })  // implicit return for ".map()"
        )
      )
    ),
    []      // "acc" is initially set to "[]" empty-array
  )
  .sort(
  // now, we have "index" - so use that to ".sort()"
    (
      {index: aIdx},    // destructure & rename index
      {index: bIdx}
    ) => aIdx - bIdx    // return 0, positive or negative to determine sort order
  )
  // finally, remove the ".index" introduced in above code
  .map(
    ( // destructure to access "index" separately
      {index, ...rest}
    ) => ({...rest})      // return only props other than "index"
  )
);

*/

const object = {
  a: [
    { name: "John", age: 32 },
    { name: "David", age: 23 },
    { name: "Justin", age: 28 },
    { name: "Arnauld", age: 35 }
  ],
  b: [
    { name: "Ivan", age: 18 },
    { name: "Nekko", age: 13 },
    { name: "Lena", age: 25 }
  ],
  c: [
    { name: "Ann", age: 19 },
    { name: "Nick", age: 14 }
  ]
};

/*const result = Object.values(object).reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const arr = cur.map((item, index) => {
    return { ...item, index: Math.floor(index / 2) };
  });
    
  return [...acc, ...arr];
}, []).sort((a,b) => a.index - b.index);*/

console.log(myTransform(object));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added to the snippet above.